# What's the meaning of nagara and when is it used?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have been looking at grammar guides on the Internet. But I'm not clear about the meaning of ながら and its usage. Could you help me with some examples and explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-ながら is appended to the -masu stem of a verb to create the sense of "while doing A also doing B".

For example:

> 歩きながら{あるきながら}音楽{おんがく}を聴いていた{きいていた}
>
> *Aruki-nagara ongaku o kiite ita.*
>
> I was listening to music while walking.